# Connect Azure SqlDatabase using my PC IP rather than my public IP

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We have a desktop application which uses Azure SQL Database. When we are in the office, we can connect to the SQL as we have included our both public and personal IPs in Azure SQL server

Firewall settings. The problem we face is on weekends when we use our desktop application from home, SQL connection couldn't be established as the IPs will not be the same as in our office. We also tried to use the application by establishing VPN to our office using Forticlient, but as my public IP remains the same we are not successful in establishing the connection to Azure SQL.

What can be done to resolve this?

Comment: what do you mean by `personal IP`?

Comment: IP that we will get when we use ipconfig in cmd prompt which will be different from search result "my ip" in google (which is my public ip)

Answer (score 0):

> What can be done to resolve this?

Only option is to add your Home IP to allowable IP addressable list

**Few more options :**

1.You can add a certain range of IP's in allowed firewall list like  `192.168.32.1 to 192.168.32.150`

**below step is not recommended ,since only ID and Password will be the last barrier**

adding below ensures everyone in the world is allowed

```
0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255
```

Comment: We cannot use this, as our users travel a lot and we cannot ask for their IP whenever they access the application.

Comment: added few more options @Joe89

Comment: We also have to see the security constraint here, my database is open to all insecurities now as it is open to all public over the world.

Comment: Will there be any way to configure something in my VPN so that all the packets move to my VPN network and from there I will route the packages to the web?

Comment: I think  they can remote desktop into a work pc,i didn't tried though